# Any vector can be written as a linear combination vectors with non-zero multiplicity

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $\{v_k\}_{k\in \mathbb{N}}$ be a non-zero sequence of vectors in $\mathbb{R}^d$. Assume that there is $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\{v_1, \ldots, v_N\}$ form a basin of $\mathbb{R}^d.$ Is it true that for every $\ell >N$, there is $t\leq N$ such that $$v_{\ell}=\lambda_1v_1+\ldots+\lambda_t v_t$$
for $\lambda_i \neq 0$ for each $i$?

Comment: Some of basis elements might be 0.  Take  $v_1=(1,0,0...,0), v_2=(0,1,...,0),..., v_N=(0,...,0,1)$ And define $(v_ \ell)_{\ell>N}$ in Any way, for example $(0,1,1,...), (0,2,2,...),...$ then always we have some $\lambda_i$ is equal to 0.

Comment: @Antares: Can All $\lambda_i$ be zero?

Comment: @Adam : Yes, all of the $\lambda_i$'s can be zero. But this uniquely represents the coordinates of the zero vector $\mathbf{0}$ in $\mathbb R^d$ w.r.t. to Antares' basis.

Comment: @math-physicist : I meant for non-zero vector

Comment: @Adam : Since you are talking about basis vectors of $\mathbb R^d$, I'll assume you are considering it as a *vector space*. And in fact, it is a consequence of the very definition of a vector space that the additive identity (which we call $\mathbf 0$) *must* be unique. (Why?) So, if some (non-zero) vector has all zero coordinates, it must be the zero vector of that vector space. This is also true for an arbitrary vector space and is independent of a choice of basis.

Comment: @math-physicist That means the only option is that all $\lambda_i$ are zero when we consider zero vector, right?

Comment: @Adam : Yes, because the additive identity for any vector space is always unique. This is in fact the very reason why we can *label* the additive identity by $\mathbf 0$ and not be left with an ambiguity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $\{v_1, \ldots, v_N\}$ is basis of space $\mathbb{R}^d$, linear combination of all vectors in the basis is equal to some vector from the space $\mathbb{R}^d$. We can take some arbitrary vector $v_l\in \mathbb{R}^d$, for some $l>N$ and let $t\le N$. That means $$v_l=\lambda_1v_1+\lambda_2v_2+\dots+\lambda_tv_t+\lambda_{t+1}v_{t+1}+\dots+\lambda_Nv_N$$
If we say $\lambda_i \neq 0$ for each $i=\overline{1,t}$ and $\lambda_i = 0$ for each $i=\overline{t+1,n}$, we can see:
$$v_l=\lambda_1v_1+\lambda_2v_2+\dots+\lambda_tv_t\tag{1}$$
So obviously this means that some $l>N$, there exists some $t\le N$ so that $(1)$ holds true.